# Magento2 - Missing required argument

Tags: magento2, module, url

I'm trying to create a block I can call in my override of 'root.phtml'.

In the root file, I added some extra classes to the body depending on the url, so I've created a module which I call on this page.

I've overridden *root.phtml* in my theme folder, and I've created a seperate module to call in this phtml file.
This is just to get the current URL (so if you have a better suggestion, please come forward) however when I try to load the application it comes up with

```
    Missing required argument $data of Karl\OverrideView\Block\OverrideView
```

The file being refered to is;

```
namespace Karl\OverrideView\Block;

class OverrideView
{

public $assetRepository;
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(

    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    array $data = [],
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
){
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    return parent::construct($context, $data);
}

public function getFullUrl(){
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl(false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your constructor you are calling `parent::construct()`, but you are not extending any class. You must extend the class to which you are override or to the class `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` and there is a typo in constructor name (two underscores are missing), the proper name is `__construct`

Also, write your constructor this way:

```
public function __construct(

    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    array $data = []
){
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    return parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

Comment: Realised I'd not given this answer any credit, Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I was having the same error, all my __constructs and Extending's are correct, if you are scratching your head wondering... why when I do:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

it breaks everything and get this error, but then when I do:

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

the same code works fine afterwards, but then would break again if you do another:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

??

Then most likely is that you have got your array $DATA in the middle of your Construct definition, this would cause this issue and the solution is to move this right to the end of your __constrct definition, see example below:

Example, this will NOT work:

```
public function __construct (
      \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $ModelContext, 
      array $Data = [],
      \Magento\Framework\Registry $Registry
```

But this will work:

```
public function __construct (
      \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $ModelContext,
      \Magento\Framework\Registry $Registry,
      array $Data = []
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, fixed my issue (BadMethodCallException).

Comment: Glad to hear that Kevin, good luck.

Comment: thanks Dude! fixed my issue too (BadMethodCallException)

Comment: Anyone figured out why the position of $data argument is affecting the code compilation ?

Comment: I believe its how the system was put together, even if someone figured it out and fixed it, the next next magento-update would likely yo break it again, ... I don't think it matters much "why" this is happening, but if you really like to know it's to do with the empty array [] passed in the middle.